# GWSMO Large Mailbox / Exclude folder from syncing with Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

We are G Suite / Google Workspace shop and have some users who use GWSMO to sync emails to Outlook.

Some users have GMail mailboxes larger than 100GB and when syncing all that data to their Outlook seems to have issues.

I'm looking for ways to handle large mailboxes. Especially I'm looking for a way to not sync specific folders in Gmail to Outlook using GWSMO. I haven't found that feature if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail doesn't use folders the same way as Outlook does. It just tags messages with Labels. All incoming mails are automatically labeled "inbox", and when you add another label and archive the mail, Gmail just removes the label "inbox".

When you open "Folder" named "Foo" in Gmail, you're actually just performing a search for mails that have label "Foo" but not label "inbox". In the Gmail web interface you can see this as the text `label:Foo` appears in the Search box.

Because of the fundamental difference in how mails are stored, such feature is unlikely to exist.

More detailed info on differences between Outlook and Gmail in [this Google Workspace Learning Center page](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/153966?hl=en&ref_topic=2801989).

Comment: Sure I understand the differences, just looking for a good way to keep Outlook's pst data file from growing to an unmanageable size.  Excluding one or more labels would essentially perform the same function.  Is there a way to limit the data file to 50GB or 75GB, from what I see the limits are 1GB, 2GB, 4GB or unlimited which aren't really that useful in todays world.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the mailbox size limit with a win reg key:
https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/184126?hl=en#Registry

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1159456)